# dispatchEvent trigger not working on element id

Tags: jquery, dispatchevent

I am facing an issue while calling `dispatchEvent` for `addEventListener` event. The code is doing exactly what I want, but the difference is that I want to call `dispatchEvent` on the button id rather than `document`.

```
function fire( elem, type ) {

  var evt = elem.createEvent("Events");

  evt.initEvent( type, true, true, window, 1);

  elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

document.addEventListener( "click", function() {
    console.log( "Fired a synthetic click event" );
}, false );

fire( document, "click" );
```

I tried replacing `document` with "button id" but it's not working.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Several small changes were necessary here, described in the comments below:

```js
function fire(elem, type) {
  console.log("Dispatching a synthetic event");
  // .createEvent() is a document function:
  var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
  evt.initEvent(type, true, true, window, 1);
  // ...but you want to dispatch it on the element:
  elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

// The event listener belongs on the element, not the document (unless you want the click event to fire whenever the user clicks anywhere on the page):
document.getElementById("theID").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Fired a click event");
}, false);

// The fire() function expects a DOM element, not just its ID:
fire(document.getElementById("theID"), "click");
```

```html
<button id="theID">Hello</button>
```