# Simulate click of a row to load the dynamic component in react

Tags: reactjs, click, element, simulate

I'm trying to replicate the click programatically in a react based application.
I'm trying below code to work this through however i'm getting dispatchevent is not a function error

I've tried out .click() for the fetched element but that didn't work out.
Now tried the below function which gives the error as below

A promise is being taken up to know that the element is loaded in window for sure

```
const triggerEvents = (element, eventName) => {
    let ev = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    ev.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
    element.dispatchEvent(ev);
}

const promises = [
    waitForElement(selector, 60000),
];
return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(element => {
        triggerEvents(element, 'click');
});


const waitForElement = (selector, maxTime = 25000) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const element = document.querySelector(selector);

    if (element !== null) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        res(element);
    }
}, 4000);

setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    rej(new Error(`${selector} not found in DOM`));
}, maxTime);
```

});

The selector in the above method is basically a table's row index for first data displayed for eg: rowIndex="2"

I've checked that my element being returned is not empty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458104/dispatchevent-trigger-not-working-on-element-id

Comment: Hi Oleg In case of the page posted by you the person has reported that he's not facing any trouble while calling dispatchevent function. in my case the issue seems to be even more different